# Can I use a new version of HttpClient in my Android project?

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to work with HttpClient 4.2.5 in an Android project (added to the classpath). The problem is that at execution time, Android takes the default HttpClient registered in its APIs. This doesn't have all classes and methods, so I have errors like:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.setRedirectStrategy

How can I fix this issue and get execution with the version in the classpath and ignore the embedded version? I tried to change order of classpath libraries - that didn't work.

Comment: What Stephen pointed out below, is basically what's already been done for you with the [`httpclientandroid`](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) project. Unfortunately, the current version seems to be stuck at HttpClient 4.2.3, but you could potentially put in a request for an update (or perhaps use it as a starting point if you decide to repackage it yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HttpClientAndroidLib](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/). As for now it is based on HttpClient 4.2.3, but I think it's quite sufficient for your needs. The author of this lib bypasses restrictions by renaming all the packages of the original HttpClient.

Comment: It works ! I think that HttpClient 4.2.3 is sufficient for my application's needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Android is getting HttpClient via its bootclasspath.  If that is the case, then the order of the JARs on the classpath is not relevant.

If this was "real Java(tm)", you would solve this by using an alternative bootclasspath when starting the JVM, but I don't think you can so this in an Android app<sup>1</sup>.

The best I can suggest is that you snarf the sources for HttpClient and its dependencies, tweak the package names throughout, and build new JARs.  Then modify your app code to use the new classes by importing with the tweaked package names.

---

<sup>1 - If they allowed an app to specify an alternative bootclasspath, it would provide a new potential attack vector for malicious apps.  I know that Android is *supposed* to implement security outside of the Davlik VM, but it is still a bad idea to remove a second line of defence implemented in the VM.</sup>